# using update in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a column named `date_col` of data-type date. What's wrong with this query?

```
update test set date_col = to_date(sysdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Only date mon and yy is visible. not the time.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try, `SELECT TO_CHAR(date_col, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') From Table`

Comment: Then edit your post and remove this - *only date mon and yy is visible*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SYSDATE is yet a date. You don't need to cast SYSDATE to date type because it is a date_

```
update test 
set date_col = sysdate
```

To see time fraction use [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm#i1009324):

```
select to_char(date_col, 'HH24 MI')
from test;
```